# 'SQL1024N A database connection does not exist. SQLSTATE=08003' error while executing 'db2 -x' command through command stage in Datastage 9.1

Tags: data-warehouse, datastage

I'm getting '**SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003**' error, while executing '**db2 -x**' command through **execute command stage in Datastage 9.1**(AIX Server). Can any one please help me out ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To connect to DB2 - you need a catalog entry on your Linux server ( or wherever the Datastage in installed)

You may need to check with the datastage administrator.

Use the below command on the server to see all the cataloged db2 databases

```
db2 list db directory
```

You may need to source the dsenv before you run this.